# Sum of triangular numbers

Tags: analytic-number-theory

What is the formula for the number of representations of a positive integer as a sum of a triangular number and three times a triangular number?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that there _is_ a nice formula? And is this just pure curiosity, or do you have some other reason to want this formula?

Comment: It was an exercise to find out in the book of Number Theory in The Spirit of Ramanujan by B C Berndt using the theorem.
 $q\psi(q^2)\psi(q^6)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{q^{6n+1}}{1-q^{12n+2}}-\frac{q^{6n+5}}{1-q^{12n+10}})$. I tried replacing $q^2$ by $q$. But If I knew the target, it would really be helpful to me.